# Is there a bootstrap class for full view height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've implemented the following css class:

```
.full-view-height {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

because I was unable to find an equivalent bootstrap class through after numerous web searches. Does such a class exist by default in bootstrap 4?

Comment: all inforamation in bootstrap site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer:

### Yes:

```
.min-vh-100
```

## Long answer:

It occurred to me while writing the question that I could just do a fulltext search on dist/css/bootstrap.css for 100vh. Most of the results were related to modals but I eventually found the following code:

```
.min-vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

It worked as expected.
I subsequently grep'ed the scss folder with a more exact query to discover that the source is a line in scss/utilities/_sizing.scss which includes a few other similar helper classes.